# Is there always a meaningful way to compare arrows for equivalence in a category that is not locally small?

Tags: category-theory

The page ["principle of equivalence"](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/principle+of+equivalence) at ncatlab.org says

> It does not break equivalence-invariance to state that two morphisms are equal, given a common source and target; this is because a hom-set is a set, where equality is meaningful.

But the page titled "hom-set" says that the hom-set is only a set for locally small categories.

Is it also true that it doesn't break what that page calls "equivalence invariance" to compare arrows in non-locally-small categories?

Comment: Size is not relevant here. The “set” in “hom-set” here is not always to be taken literally in the sense of set theory. Here it is being used as a shorthand for discrete collection.

Comment: OK, but is there a meaningful definition of equality in this "discrete collection"?

Comment: Well it seemed like you are claiming that a hom-set is always discrete, which as you point out implies that there is some definition of equality. I am interested in knowing how to prove this. It is obvious that if the hom-set is a set then there is a way to compare its elements for equality, but it is not obvious to me in the alternative case.

Comment: A hom-set _is_ always discrete. Discrete collections have equality. There is nothing to prove in my view – this is all by definition. If you have a different understanding then you should state carefully all your definitions and ask a precise question.

Comment: A polite form of Zhen's question is: what definition of non-locally-small category are you using for which you find the notion of equality unclear? Or are you asking what non-locally-small categories even are?